# Did the ending really happen in Baby Driver?

Tags: plot-explanation, baby-driver

I recently rewatched *Baby Driver* and I just noticed something at the end.

Miles receives a postcard from Debora and we see in the last scene he gets released and she's waiting for him with a shiny new Cadillac. Both are wearing 50's style outfits and there's a long rainbow in the perfect blue sky. So did that really happen or was him just dreaming?

He was supposed to be released on parole in 5 years (it must be - they haven't aged enough to be after 25 years of his sentence), but that outfit wasn't the one he got arrested with - and throughout the movie he's never seen wearing such outfits.

It sort of fits Debora's dream of going west "in a car she can't afford". Plus we see it earlier when Miles had the same sort of "vision" of her waiting for him and smiling in front of a car.

So is the ending real or just his imagination and he's still in jail?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### It's left unclear

Edgar Wright said:

> "I think the end scene is up for interpretation. And I sort of learned quickly through the test screening process that I should let people interpret it how they want. I think it's an important thing with movies where you don't have to state your actual intention because nobody's response to it is wrong. I think that's a good thing to do; you don't want to have anybody say, 'No, you're wrong, you read that wrong.' It's better if you have two different interpretations."
>
> <sup>[source](https://screenrant.com/baby-driver-movie-edgar-wright-ending-explained/)</sup>